# Do two tables with the same content break data normalization?

Tags: sql, database-normalization

[Assuming there is a one to many relationship between an individual and an address, and assuming there is a one to many relationship between an agency and an address.]

Given the following table structure:

[image]

Wouldn't you want to merge the two address tables together and instead of using a foreign key within each one use a tie table?
Like this:
[image]

Are they both valid for normalization or only one?

Comment: . . Business addresses may not be the same as individual addresses, from things like "Suite" to "c/o".  If you are storing standardized addresses then there is a stronger argument for keeping them in a single table -- for instance, to run NCOA on them.

Comment: My standard approach to normalization questions is to ask 1) Which approach is easier for storing the data; 2) Which approach is easier for using the data; 3) Which of those two trumps the other. You can't just look at normalization in a vacuum.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Whether a table is in a NF is independent of other tables. Normalization to higher NFs replaces a table by projections of it that natural join to it. That is based on FDs & JDs. A NF is a condition that a table satisfies or doesn't, and we say it is in that NF or isn't. "break data normalization?" & "valid for normalization" don't make sense. There is no normalization in this post. So: Explain as much as you can without using that word. If possible, ask your question. If you think you have to use that word, give your reference/textbook & connect what it says re normalization to what you wrote.

Comment: You have fk_address_id columns but Address has no id to be referenced. You are not clear about cardinalities: "one to many relationship between [from?] an individual/agency and [to?] an address" seems like it's trying to say that an individual/agency has multiple addresses but only one individual/agency is at an address. What are you trying to say? Do you mean 1:many for address:individual/agency? Can there be individual/agency without addresses & addresses without individual/agency? (The diagrams contribute no associated cardinalities.)

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you want to do.

In your second example with the tie tables, if I want to do a mailshot to my customers then my query has to go out to the agency tie table to exclude any agency addresses.

Of course you could have an address type column to differentiate but then you have a more complex query for your insert statement.

So although "address" is a global idea, sometimes it is easier to have it segregated by context.

Secondly, your customer data would usually be changing much more than your agency data. There may also be organisational and legal requirements around storage of personal data that make it better to separate the two.

e.g. in a health records system I want to be able to easily extract / restrict client data and to keep my configuration or commissioning data separate.

Thus in all the client systems I have used, the model tends to be the first one you describe rather than the second.